# How to handle random url string laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I am facing a problem when I use random or wrong string in URL like `localhost/sddsad44` I am getting error. I want to know how to handle this type of error.

When I hit this URL it's trying to access *view app.blade.php* parameter

```
Undefined variable: user
```

But when I hit defined URL without login middleware send back me to login page. 
but when I put wrong link in url it's give me error no matter I login or not.
I am leaning Laravel, I was try to find solution but I don't know what exactly I want to search.

Comment: By "wrong string" do you mean a user name that doesn't exist?

Comment: no! when i put wrong URL which was not define in my route. That give me error. I want to handle this error. Like if i put localhost/dashboard_random-string  it give an error. that $user is not define.

Comment: What do your routes looks like? `localhost/dashboard_random-string` has to be matching a route you defined.

Comment: Can you share the route, controller method, and view returning this error?

Comment: Sounds like you have a default value in your route that catches all strings. That route somehow requires a `user` variable.